# PHP wont reset the password

Tags: php, mysql, reset-password

i'm trying to create a password reset page using php. but the problem i have is when i enter the new password and then press the reset button the program will create a random password and save it in the db. not the one i entered before. thank you.

here is the code i used:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'inc/dbconnection.php';
    if(isset($_POST["reset-password"])){
        $name = $_GET["Fname"];
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        $confirmPassword = trim($_POST["confirmPassword"]);
        if($password == $confirmPassword) {
           $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
           $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE sec SET password= ? WHERE Fname = ?");
           $stmt->execute(array($password,$name));
           $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
           if($affected_rows) {
               $success_message = "Password is reset successfully.<br>Now you are redirecting";
               header("Refresh:3; url=loginSf.html");
           } else {
               $error_message = "Failed : <br> Password not updated";
           }} else {
            $error_message = "Password not matched";
      }  } ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reset Password</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styless.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <br><br><div id="sidebar-left"></div>
      <div class="reset"> Reset password </div><br><br>
  <form id="reserPassword" action="new_pass.php" name="reserPassword" method="post">
              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <div id="borr"> Reset Password<br>
                <?php if(!empty($success_message)) { ?>
                <?php echo $success_message ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>
                <?php echo $error_message ?>
              <?php } ?>
              <br>  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter a New Password" required>
              <br>  <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                <br><input type="submit" value="Reset Password" name="reset-password" id="forget-password">  </form></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Did you try debugging with ``var_dump($var); exit();`` on logical positions to see where the code stops working correctly because of possible wrong values?

Comment: _"the program will create a random password"_ - There's nothing in the above code that would "generate" any password. You do hash the password though (which is good). That will give you a new hash every time, if that's what you're referring to, but that is as it should.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but.. I want when I enter the new password it will be saved in the db as it is, what happened with me is the program will save another random password.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess: You have something like `$2y$10$nUT/9PN0hVuk0q3ci6aSJer1Ln05UGmWDTELUzAKU46qUExZZOD1W` in the database?
`password_hash` is used for hashing passwords[1] so that they will not be stored as plain text in the database.

It is part of PHP's password hashing functions[3]. As you stated, there is a 'random' password stored, I guess you didn't expect this but used this function as it was told to you or used in an example.

So you should read about the corresponding function to check if the password, the user uses for login is the correct password: `password_verify`[2].

A small example:

```
$password = 'im_an_apple';
// creates a hash with the current default algorithm
$hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo $hashed;
// e.g. $2y$10$nUT/9PN0hVuk0q3ci6aSJer1Ln05UGmWDTELUzAKU46qUExZZOD1W
// this string holds all needed informations:
// used hashing algorithm, salt, hash

// to verify this:
$verifiesPW = password_verify($password, $hashed);
$verifiesRandom = password_verify('assdfghj', $hashed);

var_dump($verifiesPW); // true
var_dump($verifiesRandom); // false
```

As you still might have some plain text passwords in the database, your login script could contain something like:

```
$passwordFromInput = 'im_a_banana';
$passwordFromDB = 'im_a_banana';


$isCorrectPassword = false;
$needsHash = password_get_info($passwordFromDB)['algoName'] === 'unknown'; //true

if ($needsHash) {
    $isCorrectPassword = $passwordFromInput === $passwordFromDB;
} else {
    $isCorrectPassword = password_verify($passwordFromInput, $passwordFromDB);
}

if ($isCorrectPassword && $needsHash) {
    $passwordHash = password_hash($passwordFromInput, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    // store $passwordHash in db
}
```

This uses `password_get_info`[4] to check the used algorithm for hashing. If the password was not hashed, it will return `unknown` as hash algorithm. So the password will be stored as hash when the user logs in.

References:

[1] https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41447/why-is-password-hashing-considered-so-important

[2] http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

[3] http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: Instead of just posting links to the examples, you should include them into the answer and just add the links as references.

Comment: also i wonder what this answer has to do with a password reset in this user case... `password_verify()` is meant to validate the password when logging in

Comment: @kuh-chan thank you for ur help .. so what will happen is the new password will convert to hash form then it will be saved in the db, so when the user try to log in with the new password it will not match the hash in the db.. so i need to verify the password to match the hash in my db .. ok should i do the verifying in the login page?  Sorry for my questions im still student.

Comment: yes. the verifying should happen in the login script. I'll update my answer